# Can't override defined styles on input elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, class, overriding

I want to make a input element of a specific width in px. Unfortunately, there's a file that I can't edit which sets width for forms on 100%. I tried to override it but without any effects.

HTML code:

```
<div class="float-left"><input type="text" class="upper-form"><input type="text" class="upper-form1"><input type="text" class="upper-form2"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
.float-left {
    float:left;
}
.float-left input[type="text"].upper-form {
    float: left;
    width: 85px;
}
.float-left input[type="text"].upper-form1 {
    float:left;
    width: 128px;
}
.float-left input[type="text"].upper-form2 {
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
}
```

No matter what I do (more specific declaration or nesting) it still doesn't work. !important clause also does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How the file set width to all forms. Show us the code of the file

Comment: input[type=text] {
width: 100%;
}

Comment: From the code you have provided there is nothing indicative of the issue you're having. Could you please provide a fiddle or post more of the form code?

Comment: @user3253748, you should put clarifications into the question itself. You should also edit it to refer to form fields (controls) rather than forms, if the thing you are really talking about is `input` elements, not `form` elements.

Comment: Which order are your css files included? i.e. is your overriding css file included **after** your main css file?

Comment: O.K. I've edited the question, thx. Sam, the order is correct, other overrides work perfectly but I only have problems with input elements

Comment: The `!important` clause definitely does work ( http://jsfiddle.net/u2TBJ/ ).  There must be something else going on.

Comment: O.K. sth else is overriding the styles (perhaps JS). I will have to figure this out. Thx for the replies